# How to properly read and, more importantly, write to a 3-table join in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 4 models (Payment, Vendor, Client, and Producer). A payment belongs to one Vendor and can be for multiple Clients. Each client (per payment) has one or more Producers. Each Payment-Client-Producer combination has a commission percentage that the Producer receives. The Vendor to payment association is straight forward, however the Payment-Client-Producer association is throwing me.

I created a rich join:

```
class CreateProducerPercentages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :producer_percentages do |t|
        t.references :payment
        t.references :client
        t.references :producer
        t.decimal :comp, :precision => 5, :scale => 4, :null => false, :default => 0.2
        t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :producer_percentages, [:payment_id, :client_id, :producer_id], :unique => true
  end
end
```

Created my models:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :vendor
    has_many :producer_percentages
    has_many :clients, :through => :producer_percentages
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :producer_percentages
    has_many :payments, :through => :producer_percentages
has_many :producers, :through => :producer_percentages
end

class Producer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :producer_percentages
end

class ProducerPercentage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :payment
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :producer
end
```

Viewing payments is done via a datagrid (jqGrid) with clients being a subgrid of payments and producers being a subgrid of the client subgrid.

In otherwords

```
Payment.first.clients.first.producers
```

should return only the producers associated with that payment-client combination.
I was able to get this working by adding a method to Client that took a payment as the parameter and returned producers.

```
def producers(payment)
    Producer.joins(:producer_percentages).where("payment_id = ? AND client_id = ?", payment.id, self.id)
end
```

That however didn't help with saving. For that part I'm lost. I'm thinking it's probably got to be an after_save but can't figure out how/where to implement it. Is there a preferred/conventional way of handling situations like this?

Comment: I would consider the right order in which things should be saved and then probably do it is stages vs. on big save.  e.g. Save Client and then save Payments with the link(s) to Client, then update Client to link to Payments.

Comment: Having analysed your relationships a bit more: my sense is that you should save Payment, Client and Producer each first and then create the relevant links second.  This two staged process should be almost as fast as doing it in one step as the second step is a simple insert into ProducerPercentage as all id's are know at that stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow a two staged processes:

Stage 1:

-Make sure all relevant Payments, Clients and Producers are first saved to the database.

Stage 2:

-As you now have all required ids update ProducerPercentage to include relations.

Comment: This is pretty much the direction I was thinking. Is there a way to perform validations on the relationship with respect to the payment (i.e. A payment must have at least one client and for each of those clients there must be at least one producer)?

Comment: @user3259424: The two staged process means that your models have to allow for this.  One solution is to have [conditional validations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) in your model depending on the status of the model.  Another is to have the logic performing the save in your controller validate that the supplied relationships are valid before doing the save.